# How to get the directory of file inside itself with PHP?

Tags: php, file

A.php:

```
<?php

...

?>
```

How to know the directory within itself?

**EDIT**
On windows,how to change "\" to "/"?

Comment: The phrase "directory within itself" does not make sense.  Do you mean to ask about the directory in which the file exists?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`dirname(__FILE__)`

[dirname](http://us.php.net/dirname) reference.

Answer (score 3):

`dirname(__FILE__)` to get the path of the PHP file regardless of whether the file runs on its own or is being included by other files.

`getcwd()` to get the current working directory (might not be the same as the directory the PHP file is in if it is being included by other files)

Answer (score 3):

By the way, you can get the correct "/" or "\" on any platform by using the DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR constant

Answer (score 1):

And to change separators to the correct one:

```
$filepath = str_replace(array('/', '\\'), DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $filepath);
```